# Add Background to ImageSpan

Tags: android, spannablestring, spannable, imagespan, spannablestringbuilder

I am trying to add a background span to the image. I can set a background span to strings, but the imagespan in the same string does not show the background.

This is a sample of what I want, the selected part shows an image and text with background span.

[image: Requirement]

This is what I have tried.

```
    public void applySpannable(String lastString, String changeString, int type, String title) {

        String totalString = lastString + title;
        Spannable spanText = new SpannableString(totalString);

        Drawable d;
        if (type == 1) {
            d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.type_flag_bg_red);
        } else {
            d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.type_flag_bg_red);
        }
        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
        ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);

        ForegroundColorSpan foregroundSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE);
        BackgroundColorSpan backgroundSpan = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.RED);

        spanText.setSpan(foregroundSpan, lowerBound, upperBound, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        spanText.setSpan(backgroundSpan, lowerBound, upperBound, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        spanText.setSpan(span, lastString.length(), lastString.length()+1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);



        edtAddTask.setText(spanText);
        edtAddTask.setSelection(edtAddTask.getText().toString().length());
    }
```

The string appears with background, but transparent image is shown without background. I have set the lower index ahead of image position.

Thanks

Comment: you are not using `ImageSpan span` at all, what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to set a background to the imagespan as shown in the image above. Background span sets the background for string but it does not set any background to imagespan.

Comment: ok so what is your image and what is the backgrounf you want to set? most likely you need `LayerDrawable` that draws multiple `Drawables` as layers

Comment: Will it be possible to change the portion  of edittext String  with LayerDrawable

Comment: i have no idea what you mean

Comment: Here is a link of a demo video. Can you please have a look. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tl6NLN9suGzgGM3GeStR-EeBbB-kAZI7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Suresh Basnet  have you got the solution for this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use BackgroundColorSpan and ImageSpan at the same time. The idea is creating an ImageSpan from [LayerDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable) with background and image layers. Please look at the following code:

**Try this for java:**

```
Spannable span = new SpannableString("This is   ic launcher with background");
Drawable myImage = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
ShapeDrawable background = new ShapeDrawable();
background.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{background, myImage});
layerDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 64, 64);
ImageSpan image = new ImageSpan(layerDrawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
span.setSpan(image, 8, 9, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

textView.setText(span);
```

**For kotlin:**

```
val span: Spannable = SpannableString("This is   ic launcher with background")
val myImage: Drawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
val background = ShapeDrawable()
background.paint.color = Color.RED
val layerDrawable = LayerDrawable(arrayOf(background, myImage))
layerDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 64, 64)
val image = ImageSpan(layerDrawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE)
span.setSpan(image, 8, 9, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

textView.setText(span)
```

From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60150320/6160172